# How to configure JVM to call custom method instead of Main method?

Tags: java, jvm

We know that JVM looks for main() method during class execution. Can we customize JVM to execute our own custom function instead of main method by default?
if yes, how do we do it?

Comment: Nope. But you can write a main method that will just call the other method that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `main(String[])` method is the Java [**entry point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java). You can package your application as a jar then you can set the `Main-Class` and run it like `java -jar myapp.jar`. See also [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). That being said, any `static` initialization blocks will run *before* `main`. But you get an exception if the class specified doesn't have a `main` method. The only other exceptions I can think of are Servlets and (the *almost* dead) Applets.

Comment: Even servlet containers have to have a main, it's just not part of your own deployment package.

Comment: @chrylis Web browsers have a main too, so even with applets that statement is true. Just trying to think outside the box on the question.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: only if the Webbrowser is implemented in Java. Otherwise, there is no reason for it to have a `main` method.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: C has no methods at all, hence no “`main` method” either. The name coincidence is irrelevant anyway, as the question is about the JVM’s search for a `main` method in a Java class. Besides that, a web browser can be implemented in any language, it doesn’t have to be C or C++.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by implementing a *native custom launcher* as described here:

- http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0709/chamberlain/index.html

But frankly, it is not worth the effort if you simply want to use a different convention for the entry point.  A simpler approach is to write a "proxy" entry point class with a conventional `main` method, have that find / load / call your "real" entry point.

On the other hand, if your goal is to execute some code before the `main` method gets called, one trick is to put the code into a *static initializer block* in the entry point class.  For example:

```
   public class Entry {
       static {
           System.out.println("Hello world");
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // ...
       }
   }
```

will print "Hello world" before the `main` method is called.

---

<sup>**Speculation!** It might also be possible identify the hidden Java bootstrapping class that finds / loads / calls the normal entrypoint class. Then you could replace it by adding a modified version to the bootstrap classpath.  However, you will be straying into dangerous territory.  Interference with hidden mechanisms is liable to end badly if you get it wrong.</sup>