# Is the Java "public static void main(string[] args)" the only way to create a main method?

Tags: java

I want to know if the "Java main method" is the only way to create a main method in java.

The Java main method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    //example code

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You can't create a main method but THE main method. It is the entry point in all Java applications. Welcome to SO, btw!

Comment: As far as I am concerned the function/method shown is what is known as "the java main method"

Comment: JVM requires the main method to be included as it is.

Comment: You can use `String...` instead of `String[]`. And you don't have to call the parameter `args`. So it doesn't have to be _exactly_ like that. What are you actually after?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173474/can-we-execute-a-java-program-without-a-main-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682655/how-to-configure-jvm-to-call-custom-method-instead-of-main-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443459/why-main-method-is-needed-in-java-main-class

Comment: What  other way did you have in mind?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I was thinking something like the c++ main method.

Comment: Java isn't C/C++, so why would you think that? Because of the C like syntax?

Comment: @Kayaman No, but rather because "int main()" is a lot shorter than Java's main method. Basically, I just wanted to know if there was a shorter main method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JVM requires an entry point to start the execution and this entry point is defined as below in JVM

`public static void main(String[] args)`

So to answer your question, you can define a `main` method with any access modifier or with/without `static` keyword, but then it is not a valid main method, as the main method which the JVM uses as an entry-point should be defined as such.

Answer (score 4):

*Equivalenty*, yes, but *syntactically* - NO!

All of these are valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

public static void main(String[] foo)

public static void main(String... args)
```

Notice they are all an effectively equivalent method signature.

edit: one more -

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

edit: for interest's sake, final is implicit but can be added

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
```

Final note: even though variations are valid, it's usually best to stick with *convention* and go with the default.

Comment: You forgot `String args[]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

There was the hackish version removed in java7, leveraging static initializers.
In java8 the initializer will still takeover, but needs an unused `main` method.

**Not for actual use :)**

```
public class Test {

   static {
     System.out.println("Hello world");
     System.exit(0);
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create as many variations of main() methods you want like:-

```
int main(int i){...}
String main(){...}
etc....
```

But

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {...}  // JVM will call only this main method
```

This will be only considered as entry point to program.